# Algorithm to randomly select order of speakers works but often results in an endless loop

Tags: c

I created the following algorithm (for a real problem and for fun) to randomly determine the order of asking questions for seven school board candidates in a debate such that:

- Each candidate is asked 7 questions
- Each candidate answers exactly once in position 1, position 2, etc.
- Candidates do not always follow in the same order (randomized order but constrained to the first two rules)

This algorithm works, producing random output constrained to the rules, but often gets stuck looping endlessly (or appearing to). I've been unable to determine why this happens despite stepping through the code w/ additional logging / break points.

Note: this algorithm has not been generalized or optimized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 7
#define NUM_COLUMNS 7

int debate_order[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLUMNS];
int candidate_used[NUM_ROWS];

void print_debate_order()
{
    int row, column;

    for(column = 0; column < NUM_COLUMNS; column++) {
        printf("Questions #%d\n", column);
        for(row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++)
            printf("  Candidate #%d\n", debate_order[column][row]);
    }
}

void set_unused(int *array, int size)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = -1;
}

int in_row(int candidate_num, int current_row)
{
    int column;
    for(column = 0; column < NUM_COLUMNS; column++)
        if( debate_order[column][current_row] == -1 ) // reached end of columns filled in
            break;
        else if ( debate_order[column][current_row] == candidate_num ) // found the candidate in this row
            return(1);
    return(0);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int row, column;
    int rand_candidate;

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for(column = 0; column < NUM_COLUMNS; column++)
        set_unused(&debate_order[column][0],NUM_COLUMNS);

    for(column = 0; column < NUM_COLUMNS; column++) {
        set_unused(candidate_used, NUM_COLUMNS);
        for (row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++ ) {
            do {
                rand_candidate = rand() % 7;
            } while(candidate_used[rand_candidate] == 1 || in_row(rand_candidate, row));
            candidate_used[rand_candidate] = 1;
            debate_order[column][row] = rand_candidate;
        }
    }

    print_debate_order();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a flaw in your algorithm.

I added `print_debate_order()` in the inner `for` loop to see how far the program gets. Here is one output of the last loop before entering an endless while:

```
Questions #0
  Candidate #2
  Candidate #6
  Candidate #1
  Candidate #3
  Candidate #0
  Candidate #5
  Candidate #4
Questions #1
  Candidate #0
  Candidate #3
  Candidate #4
  Candidate #2
  Candidate #5
  Candidate #1
  Candidate #6
Questions #2
  Candidate #4
  Candidate #2
  Candidate #6
  Candidate #5
  Candidate #3
  Candidate #0
  Candidate #1
Questions #3
  Candidate #5
  Candidate #4
  Candidate #0
  Candidate #1
  Candidate #6
  Candidate #3
  Candidate #2
Questions #4
  Candidate #3
  Candidate #5
  Candidate #2
  Candidate #0
  Candidate #4
  Candidate #6
  Candidate #-1
Questions #5
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
Questions #6
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
  Candidate #-1
```

As you can see, for question 4 there is only one candidate left, candidate 1. But if you look at the previous questions, you see that he already has the last spot for question 2. Therefore there is no candidate allowed to take the last spot for question 4 and your while loop tries to find one endlessly.

If you want to choose uniformly from all assignments to questions satisfying your conditions, you would have to start over as soon as something like this happens, i.e. your while loop would need to keep track of the candidates already tested and if none is left everything has to start from the beginning. However this will also end in very long runs depending on the number of candidates and questions, but at least there wont be an endless loop.

What you want to generate here is known as a [(uniformly distributed) latin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square). Generating them is not necessarily trivial, [here is a discussion on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63131/generate-random-latin-squares).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind when you are debugging a random involved program, always the seed to the generator (`srand` for here) should be static until you have the algorithm working (at least for that seed) — then the seed should be controllable at least until you're confident it is working all the time.  It can also be worth reporting the seed.

For example replace:

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

with

```
srand(0);
```

You can change the seed to get your desired error and then work on it.

The reason for this is that you always get the same set of random numbers generated and then debugging will be much simpler.

Comment: I like your advice about keeping the seed under control. However, I get anomalous output from your code sometimes. For example, my first test run got candidate 0 answering first on 3 questions, which isn't supposed to happen. Some other runs were not so blatantly broken.

Comment: @jonathanLeffler well I guess you should kind of study probability theory, if its random it means there is no meaning in "supposed to happen" what you got has a probability of 7^-3 I guess. and this is not a very unlikely probability. And when you want to point out a problem you need to find a seed that creates the problem and then report the seed here so one can regenerate the malfunctioned code, otherwise such condition is not traceable.

Comment: See the question.  "Each candidate answers in position 1 once, …"

Comment: @jonathanLeffler yup I agree now, didn't notice that part of the question. will edit the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my rewrite below, I've run with @Eichhörnchen's analysis and recast this as a latin square generation problem.  I've used simple latin square logic with the intent that you can upgrade it to a better one.  I've also tried to attack the rows and columns mixups by introducing more of the problem domain into the variable naming:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_CANDIDATES 7
#define NUM_QUESTIONS 7

int debate_order[NUM_QUESTIONS][NUM_CANDIDATES];

void print_debug_order() {

    for (int question = 0; question < NUM_QUESTIONS; question++) {

        for (int candidate = 0; candidate < NUM_CANDIDATES; candidate++) {
            printf("%d ", debate_order[question][candidate] + 1);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_debate_order() {

    for (int question = 0; question < NUM_QUESTIONS; question++) {
        printf("Question #%d\n", question + 1);

        for (int candidate = 0; candidate < NUM_CANDIDATES; candidate++) {
            printf("\tCandidate #%d\n", debate_order[question][candidate] + 1);
        }
    }
}

// based on http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/shuffle.html
void shuffle_array(int array[], size_t length) {

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i ++) {
        int random = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (length - i) + 1);

        int temporary = array[random];
        array[random] = array[i];
        array[i] = temporary;
    }
}

void generate_latin_square(int square[NUM_QUESTIONS][NUM_CANDIDATES]) {

    int candidates[NUM_CANDIDATES];

    for (int candidate = 0; candidate < NUM_CANDIDATES; candidate++) {
        candidates[candidate] = candidate;
    }

    shuffle_array(candidates, NUM_CANDIDATES);

    for (int candidate = 0; candidate < NUM_CANDIDATES; candidate++) {
        for (int question = 0; question < NUM_QUESTIONS; question++) {
            square[question][candidates[candidate]] = (question + candidate) % NUM_CANDIDATES;
        }
    }
    // print_debug_order();
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    generate_latin_square(debate_order);

    print_debate_order();

    return 0;
}
```

To see the latin square at the heart of the solution, uncomment the call to `print_debug_order()`

**UPDATE**

Although my code worked when # of candidates = # of questions, I tried making them not equal and wasn't happy with the results.  I reworked it so it now functions if # candidates != # questions.  Note that the OP's bullet point 3 suffers slightly when # of questions > # of candidates but it still produces workable results.  (# of candidates > # of questions doesn't have this issue.)

Comment: Is it just on my machine, or does this end up printing the candidates in the same order (except for rotation) on successive rounds (contrary to bullet 3 of the question)?  I got, for example: `Question #1 Candidate #1 Candidate #2 Candidate #6 Candidate #5 Candidate #3 Candidate #4 Candidate #7` … `Question #6 Candidate #4 Candidate #7 Candidate #1 Candidate #2 Candidate #6 Candidate #5 Candidate #3`
… `Question #7 Candidate #7 Candidate #1 Candidate #2 Candidate #6 Candidate #5 Candidate #3 Candidate #4`
where each row is a rotation of 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  yes, that's why it was a very simple latin square, it fell short on bullet 3.  I assumed the OP would upgrade it, but, for you, I've added a shuffle of the candidates (rotations) which should fix the issue.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you, and thanks to all who provided answers!